# Structural comparison of two ASTs in Eclipse

Tags: java, comparison, eclipse-plugin

I am working on an incremental builder for Java code in Eclipse. Eclipse provides a ResourceDelta that tells me which resources have changed since the last build. However, I would like to have more detailed information, e.g. what methods or what field definitions changed. There seems to be functionality similar to what I want in the "compare with -> each other" view. However, this code is quite disconnected from the build engine and seems incompatible with ResourceDeltas. What would be a good way to figure out what I want? The best solution I can see is to compare two ASTs, but I also could not find any built-in support for that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`JavaCore` does supply this information via the `IElementChangedListener` and `IJavaElementDelta` interfaces.  Here's a quick code sample to get you started:

`JavaCore.addElementChangedListener(new MyJavaElementChangeReporter(), ElementChangedEvent.POST_RECONCILE);`

More details available in [Manipulating Java code](http://help.eclipse.org/help33/topic/org.eclipse.jdt.doc.isv/guide/jdt_api_manip.htm) from the JDT Plug-in Developer Guide.

Comment: That looks just like what I need. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Thanks for the information. I am in a similar situation as @user66237, however, I am looking for fine grained changes. That is, I'm looking to obtain exactly what changes when the IJavaElementDelta.F_CONTENT flag is set. For example, I want to know if there is a new method call in the body of a method. If so, I would like to know which method is being called. Is there any way to achieve this with this API?